# Execute a XCopy operation after all the projects build in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a .proj file which is configured to execute a solution file which in turn build all the projects in the solution.
I want to add an XCopy operation which should copy the .dll files of all projects to another location only after all the projects build is completed.
I have tried with below, but it is not copying the dlls.
I am newbie in writing MSBuild tags, so it could be that I may be wrong in choosing this approach to write the task in this way.

Please provide a solution, if anyone knows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release|Debug'"/>
    <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' == ''">x64</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <SolutionToBuild>
      <Properties>Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)</Properties>
      <Targets>Clean;Build</Targets>
    </SolutionToBuild>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>  
    <SolutionToBuild Include="..\Seg\Algorithms.sln" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build"  >
      <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild)" Targets="%(SolutionToBuild.Targets)" Properties="%(SolutionToBuild.Properties)" BuildInParallel="false" ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Clean">
      <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild)" Targets="Clean" Properties="%(SolutionToBuild.Properties)" BuildInParallel="false" ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
  
  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyDestination>..\Extern\Algo\bin\$(Configuration)\</CopyDestination>
    <CopySource>..\Seg\Algorithms\$(Configuration)\DoBin\</CopySource>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToCopy Include="$(CopySource)*.dll"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuildStep Include ="@(FilesToCopy)">
      <Message>Copying..</Message>
      <Command> XCOPY %(Identity)  $(CopyDestination) /f  /y </Command>     
    </CustomBuildStep>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomBuildAfterTargets>Build</CustomBuildAfterTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>  
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of Targets as methods that are called. They run in sequence, so you just need to put your copy after the solution build:

```
<Target Name="Build">
      <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionToBuild)" Targets="%(SolutionToBuild.Targets)" Properties="%(SolutionToBuild.Properties)" BuildInParallel="false" ContinueOnError="false" />        

      <ItemGroup>
         <FilesToCopy Include="..\Seg\Algorithms\$(Configuration)\DoBin\*.dll" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="..\Extern\Algo\bin\$(Configuration)\" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Great!! You saved my day... Thanks a lot GazTheDestroyer..... I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: You should also accept it, because it solved your problem